# Prevent letters from input is not working how I want

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code: https://codepen.io/ion-ciorba/pen/MWVWpmR

The problem is on "Suma solicitata" value, there you can click and edit the value, but when trying to replace a number inside the whole one, the newly replaced number will go to the end of it. How can I fix this, I think it's because of that:

```
var preventOnlyLetters = function (event) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]+/, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you are triggering this function both on keypress and keyup. You should only have it on either keyup or keypress. But I think it would be much better if you just make the input `type="number"`

Comment: It's working better, but it is still going to the end of the input box. Can I also prevent that?

Comment: The marker will always go to the end of the input when you are replacing the input value